# How to best optimize this MariaDB query

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization

Trying to optimize a query that keeps end up using "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" and takes nearly 2 seconds to go through. All matches in the query are either indexed or a primary key.

It's just grabbing the last few comments across the website articles, and listing them, but it needs to grab stuff like title from the article and username from users.

The query:

```
SELECT
    c.`comment_id`,
    c.`article_id`,
    c.`time_posted`,
    a.`title`,
    a.`slug`,
    u.username,
    a.`date`
FROM
    `articles_comments` c
INNER JOIN `articles` a ON
    c.`article_id` = a.`article_id`
INNER JOIN `users` u ON
    u.user_id = c.author_id
WHERE
    a.`active` = 1 AND c.`approved` = 1
ORDER BY
    c.`comment_id`
DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_comments` (
  `comment_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `guest_username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_posted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `spam` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `spam_report_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_edited` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_edited_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edit_counter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `total_likes` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `lock_timer` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked_by_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `promoted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin;


ALTER TABLE `articles_comments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  ADD KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
  ADD KEY `article_id` (`article_id`),
  ADD KEY `approved` (`approved`),
  ADD KEY `last_edited` (`last_edited`),
  ADD KEY `time_posted` (`time_posted`);


ALTER TABLE `articles_comments`
  MODIFY `comment_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `article_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `guest_username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guest_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guest_ip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `edit_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_submitted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `tagline` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `comment_count` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `show_in_menu` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `views` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `submitted_article` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `admin_review` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `reviewed_by_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `submitted_unapproved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `comments_open` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `draft` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `tagline_image` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail_alt_text` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gallery_tagline` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `locked_by` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preview_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_likes` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `moderated_comments` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;


ALTER TABLE `articles`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`),
  ADD KEY `date` (`date`),
  ADD KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
  ADD KEY `slug` (`slug`);
ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`text`);
ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `title_2` (`title`);
ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`);


ALTER TABLE `articles`
  MODIFY `article_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;



CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `register_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(233) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `supporter_email` varchar(233) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supporter_type` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `supporter_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `supporter_plus_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `supporter_last_paid_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `show_supporter_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_group` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
  `secondary_user_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_count` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `avatar` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_picture` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar_uploaded` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `avatar_gallery` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `forum_posts` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `steam` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_bio` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `about_me` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_on_profile` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ban_reason` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `oauth_uid` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oauth_provider` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_subscribe` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `auto_subscribe_email` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `email_on_pm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `theme` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supporter_link` text NOT NULL,
  `hide_developer_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `youtube` text NOT NULL,
  `steam_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `steam_username` text NOT NULL,
  `distro` text NOT NULL,
  `public_email` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `auto_subscribe_new_article` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `facebook` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_options` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
  `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `activation_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitch` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `mastodon` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `gogprofile` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_mod_queue` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `mod_approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `login_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `pc_info_public` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `pc_info_filled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `per-page` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 30,
  `articles-per-page` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 15,
  `forum_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normal_forum',
  `single_article_page` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `submission_emails` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `game_developer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `display_comment_alerts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `display_quote_alerts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `display_like_alerts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `admin_comment_alerts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `timezone` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `google_email` text NOT NULL,
  `email_articles` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mailing_list_key` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `global_search_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `get_pms` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `private_profile` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `social_stay_cookie` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `lifetime_supporter` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `profile_address` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hide_adverts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `full_rss_key` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin;




ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Using Explain gives me this:

```
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    17487   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    
1   SIMPLE  c   ref author_id,article_id,approved   article_id  4   gamingonlinux.a.article_id  5   Using index condition; Using where  
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   gamingonlinux.c.author_id   1   Using where
```

This is on MariaDB 10.6

Comment: You have tagged both mysql and mariadb. Which one are you using? They are different products, and not wholly compatible. The best answer might depend on the brand and version you are using. Please run `SELECT VERSION();` and include the response in your question.

Comment: Apologies, it's MariaDB 10.6

Comment: Your EXPLAIN output (thank you for including it) shows that some indexes are present in these tables, but your DDL doesn't show the index definitions.

Comment: I think I've added what you mean from the exports.

Answer (score 1):

When I test your query on [Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZUSI3ilS), I see the EXPLAIN shows a different output:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | c | ref | author_id,article_id,approved | approved | 1 | const | 1 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | fiddle.c.article_id | 1 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | u | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | fiddle.c.author_id | 1 | Using where |

You can see this eliminates the filesort and temporary table. Both of these are likely to degrade performance.

This version of the EXPLAIN also makes the joins into `type: eq_ref` joins, which means they are doing lookups on tables `a` and `u` by their respective primary key. The first table `c` is using a secondary key lookup, indicated by `type: ref`.

I'm testing with zero rows in my test tables, which often results in a different optimization strategy, because the cost estimates are different. But it shows it's possible to get a better optimization with your current indexes.

It's always worth trying to run `ANALYZE TABLE` to make sure the optimizer has current statistics for the indexes, so its estimates are more accurate. This command is quick and safe to run on an InnoDB table at any time.

If that doesn't help, then you may have to use a query hint to force a specific order of table joins. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/index-hints-how-to-force-query-plans/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out giving the hint SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN solved the problem.